# Sliding panel jumping back to home when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I made a vertical sliding panel on a 1page website (click psssst on the top right).
All in all it works fine, it slides up and down properly (still a little bump on the button when sliding, but no biggy).

The problem is when you scroll to the right and then click the sliding panel it jumps back to the beginning of the page.

How can i fix/prevent this?
You can view the problem here: http://www.basenharald.nl/3d

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have **two** problems:

### The first problem (you've already fixed it, I think)

The click event on the anchor is sending you to the '/#' URL. This happens because the anchor element has an href of "#" and the **default** behavior of the browser is to send you to that URL.

In order to *prevent* that from happening, you should use `e.preventDefault()` in your click event handlers, or `return false` **if you want to stop all event propagation** (because that's how jQuery works).

### The second problem

It seems that even after preventing the default behavior, clicking on '#open' or '#close' is still bringing the Scroller back to the initial state. In firebug I can see that there is a handler for the click event on those elements that is causing this to happen. You can see it yourself by running this in firebug:

```
console.log($('#close')[0].onclick.toString())
```

You'll see this:

```
function () {
  Scroller.end(this);
  l = this.hash.substr(1);
  a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].name == l) {
      clearInterval(Scroller.interval);
      Scroller.interval = setInterval("Scroller.scroll(" + Scroller.offsetParent(a[i]) + ")", 10);
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that somewhere in your code you're assigning an event handler to **all anchors**, and the line

```
Scroller.interval = setInterval("Scroller.scroll(" + Scroller.offsetParent(a[i]) + ")", 10);
```

is what's causing your Scroller to "reset", "go back" or something.

Maybe the problem is the conditional? Maybe `if (a[i].name == l)` is always evaluating to **true** and ends up assigning the event handler to **all** anchors even though that's not its intent.

I don't know enough about your app and/or whatever plugins you're using, so I can only tell you where the problem is, and it's in this function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help Alexander! The solution was much simpler then i thought though. The javascript handles the click function so my <a> does not need to have the href="#". once that was removed, the problem was solved. Since you took that much time to write the whole above i will mark your answer as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `return false;` to your click handlers:

```
// Expand Panel
$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    return false;
}); 

// Collapse Panel
$("#close").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault()` (and declare the **e** parameter in the function signature, i.e `$("#close").click(function(e){)...` instead of `return false;`. In jQuery, `return false;` will prevent the default behavior and stop all bubbling (potentially breaking other even handlers you might have attached or will in the future), so it's a better idea to call `e.preventDefault()` specifically.

Comment: @Alexander it worked, but somehow it does not work anymore. A little more help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Luuk I've added an answer, since it's too long for a comment